# how to convert a python dictionary into a graph object, NetworkX

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx, sna

I'm new to python, and I am trying to convert a dictionary into a graph object in Networkx. The dictionary:

```
dict = {'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], 'key2': ['value1', 'value2']}
```

I want the keys to be an ego node, and values to be their alter nodes (with out-degree going from an ego to an alter). Is this possible to achieve in Python?.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over keys just by using the dictionary as an iterable:

```
for key in d:
    #...
```

and, as you probably already know, you access values in the dictionary using the key as "index":

```
d[key]
```

Iterating over lists (which your dictionary values are) is similar to iterating over the keys of the dictionary.

Combining these pieces of knowledge with the excellent [networkx example on creating graphs](https://networkx.github.io/examples.html) should be straightforward, so you should try it, and ask a new question if you have any *specific* problem

Comment: Thanks, also from_dict_of_lists Networkx function works well. I should have read the manual first.